# Error when trying to add an image

Tags: graphics, packages

I am a LaTeX newb and I am trying to learn how to add an image, picture etc. in  my text.
However, I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can someone point me out in the irght direction?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht]
**\includegraphics[label= 1]{mango.png}**
\caption{Everyone love mango bango!}
\label{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: label= 1 is not a known option for includegraphics. What should it do?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine with me but not centered. Also you don't need to add "**" beside the command.

Try this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 

    \begin{figure}[ht]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example.png}
     \caption{write your caption here}
     \label{write your label here}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Also, you can change the size of the figure by changing the width.